# Glympse for Android: Obtaining API key

Tags: android, api, key, glympse

I want to make use of the Glympse functionality in my Android app by using the Glympse SDK for Android, but when I try to run the Demo projects I get the message:

"Valid API key has not been configured. Please visit http://developer.glympse.com if you need a key."

Am I required to configure a key even when test-running an application? If so, how do I obtain such a key, by sending a request-mail? All help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you press the "Get Started" button on the page that it tells you to visit, it lists the five steps you need to go through to develop, test and launch your app. I'm not sure how we can be any clearer than Glympse are about what you need to do to develop against their API.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, Glympse SDK requires at least a "Sandbox" API key to test run -- but don't worry, this is very easy and fast to get:

1. Click sign-in to create an account.
2. Visit https://developer.glympse.com/apps to register a new application with the Glympse server -- doing this automatically creates a Sandbox API key for you.

You can access this apps/keys page from either the 5-step Getting Started page, or under the "My Account" > "My Apps" drop-down in the upper-right.  Once you're ready to ship your app, you can request a production key through this same page.

Comment: Thanks. Now, how can we put in the API (Sandbox) key?

Comment: Ah, found it. For create lite demo, it's in GlympseLiteWrapper.java file. Replace `public static final String API_KEY = "<< Your API key >>";` with your own.